# Running bitcoin-qt on a server

Tags: server

I need a full Bitcoin node running on a server. It's a Windows server - is there any advantage to running bitcoind over bitcoin-qt? I need the JSON API, to they need the server flag, I just figured that if something goes amiss it would be easier to take a quick look at the wallet if the GUI us running as opposed to the console.